# search using a search bar by a button click in typeahead?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, angularjs-bootstrap

Here is my Form..

```
div.form(name='customerFrm')
label.fa.fa-search.search-icon(data-ng-click= "customer(obj._id)", typeahead-match) 

input.form-control.search(type='text', ng-model='selected', typeahead-on-select= "customerSearch()")
```

and this is the plugin that I am using for Angular Bootstrap ..

First file..

```
a(tabindex='-1', bind-html-unsafe='match.model.name | typeaheadHighlight:query', ng-href='account.html#!/abc/{{match.model._id}}')
```

and this is the second file ..

```
ul.dropdown-menu(aria-hidden='{{!isOpen()}}', role='listbox', style='display: block;', 
        ng-style='{top: position.top+"px", left: position.left+"px"}', ng-if='isOpen()')

li(role='option', ng-click='selectMatch($index)', ng-mouseenter='selectActive($index)',
        ng-class='{active: isActive($index) }', ng-repeat='match in matches track by $index')
div(template-url='templateUrl', query='query', match='match', index='$index',
        typeahead-match='')
```

using first file it returns me ...

```
href="account.html#!/abc/
```

path but not with it's id. So please give me a solution how to redirect to the page with it's id.